# Using filter to select specific values of ,multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, multiple-columns

Trying to use filter function in R and selecting only values needed in multiple columns and also including missing values.

```
x <- 1:2:3:4:5:NA
y <- 3:4:NA:5:6:NA
z <- 2:3:4:NA:5:6
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

df %>% 
  filter(x !=  1, 2, 3 | is.na(x))
```

I am trying to filter to values more than 4 in columns x, y and z keeping NA. Using the attempt above gives an error 'input must be logical vector, not a double'. Any suggestion to rectify the above error and also how to apply this command to all three columns.

Comment: You are hurting yoursef. Take a simple R book and learn the basics. How to create a vector etc. The answers given will not be helpful if you dont even understand R syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, please provide a reproducible example:

```
x <- c(1:5, NA)
y <- c(3:4, NA, 5:6, NA)
z <- c(2:4, NA, 5:6)
```

Then I would recommend using the package `{data.table}`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x, y, z)
```

And then you can apply filters like so

```
dt[x >= 4 | is.na(x), ]
```

(meaning, give me all rows of the table where x is greater or equal to 4 or where x is NA.)

You can further combine other logical constraints:

```
dt[(x >= 4 | is.na(x)) | (y >= 4 | is.na(y)) | (z >= 4 | is.na(z)), ]
```

Further information on the `{data.table}` syntax can be found here: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using dplyr:

```r
df = data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5,NA),
  y = c(3,4,NA,5,6,NA),
  z = c(2,3,4,NA,5,6)
)

df %>%
  filter(
    x >= 4 | is.na(x),
    y >= 4 | is.na(y),
    z >= 4 | is.na(z)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R

```
subset(df, pmin(x, y, z, na.rm = TRUE)>=4)

   x  y  z
4  4  5 NA
5  5  6  5
6 NA NA  6
```

in case you have very man columns and do not want to reference them by name:

```
subset(df, do.call(pmin, c(na.rm = TRUE, df)) >=4)
   x  y  z
4  4  5 NA
5  5  6  5
6 NA NA  6
```